# How can i delete the row correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My jquery code :

```
   //i can get the id correctly
  id = $(this).parent().parent().children('td.idName').text(); 

 //it seems that i have invoke the wrong function 
 $('.confirmDeleteButton').click(function () { 
      $(".idName:contains('" +id + "')").parent().remove();
 });
```

I have a   table with many row ,  when i click the confirmDeleteButton ,it should  delete  the  row .
for example **if id = 1**
it means that i should delete this row

```
<tr>
   <td class="idName">1</td>   //id =1;
   <td><button class="delete "  > delete</td>
</tr>
```

but in fact , it delect

```
<tr>
   <td class="idName">1</td>   //id = 1
   <td><button class="delete "  > delete</td>
</tr>   
<tr>
    <td class="idName">10</td>   //id =10
    <td><button class="delete ">delete</td>
</tr>
```

it seems that if **id = 1** it will delete all row  with **1** such as **11 ,111, 101,21 etc.**

My problem is that **What is the correct way to delete the correct row by id?**

Comment: Your question is a *perfect* example of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You're asking a question based on what you *think* is the right way to do it, but it is actually not the right way to achieve your end goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `contains` method it's a wrong thing. You can use `forEach` method which accepts a `callback` method.

```js
var id=1;
$('.confirmDeleteButton').click(function () {
      Array.from($(".idName")).forEach(function(item){
        if($(item).text().trim()=="1")
          $(item).parent().remove();
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tr>
   <td class="idName">1</td>
   <td><button class="delete"> delete</td>
</tr> 
<tr>
   <td class="idName">1</td>
   <td><button class="delete"> delete</td>
</tr>   
<tr>
    <td class="idName">10</td>
    <td><button class="delete">delete</td>
</tr>
</table>
<button class="confirmDeleteButton">Confirm</button>
```

Comment: This is super-convoluted. You could have just used `$(".idName").filter(...)` - but once again.... this is the wrong solution to a very simple problem.

Comment: @Jamiec, filter just creates a new array by calling a provided callback solution for every item

Comment: Maybe OP wants to do this. It's like to delete more rows simultaneous.

Answer (score 4):

> What is the correct way to delete the correct row by id?

Don't do that, delete the row relative to the button you've clicked.

```js
$('.delete').on('click',function(){
  $(this).parents("tr").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
   <td class="idName">1</td>  
   <td><button class="delete"  > delete</td>
</tr>   
<tr>
    <td class="idName">10</td> 
    <td><button class="delete">delete</td>
</tr>  
</table>
```